# Filter using xPathUtils.compile() on select

Tags: java, xpath

I am parsing a hdom object which is a list of resources returned. They are of the format
The Sample XML is as follows

```
<ResourceList>     
    <Resource>
        <isValid>0</isValid>
        <keyValue>ABC</keyValue>
    </Resource>     
    <Resource> 
        <isValid>0</isValid>    
        <keyValue>PQR</keyValue>  
    </Resource>     
    <Resource>
        <isValid>1</isValid>
        <keyValue>XYZ</keyValue>
     </Resource>
</ResourceList>
```

When I use the following filter, it correctly returns `ABC` `XpathUtils.compile("ResourceList/Resource/keyValue").select(SampleXML)` 
However I want to filter on `isValid` flag `1` and return the key Value `XYZ`.
How do I apply the filter on XpathUtils function .compile, please?

Sorry if its too basic as I am somewhat new to java.

Tried setting up filters but seem to get null as an output

Comment: By the way, there are many Java libraries which include a class named "XPathUtils" or "XpathUtils", so it's a good idea to be clear as to which you are using, ideally by including full Java source code (which would show the `import` statement for the `XPathUtils` class showing what package it belongs to). But in this case it doesn't matter since the problem has a solution in XPath itself (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an XPath "predicate" (a boolean expression enclosed in square brackets) to filter the set of `Resource` elements, and then return the `keyValue` child elements from that filtered set. e.g.

```
ResourceList/Resource[isValid='1']/keyValue
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates